# Vim: join lines by replacing ^M

Tags: sed, vim

I have a file which has embedded `^M` characters. I wish to join the lines at the `^M` character.

ie: change this:

```
 ^M
            être, ^M
            étant, ^M
            été,Indicatif,Présent,suis,es,est,sommes,êtes,sont
 ^M
            être, ^M
            étant, ^M
            été,Indicatif,Imparfait,étais,étais,était,étions,étiez,étaient
```

to this:

```
être,étant,été,Indicatif,Présent,suis,es,est,sommes,êtes,sont
être,étant,été,Indicatif,Imparfait,étais,étais,était,étions,étiez,étaient
```

This command removes the `^M` but the lines are not joined:

```
%s/\r//g
```

Comment: `%s/\r\n//g` might work.

Comment: This might help also:  First I used  `tr -d \\r <source> destfile`  then `sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\([[:blank:]]\)é*//;ta' -e 'P;D'` destfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^M` is a Windows-specific EOL (End Of Line) and it consists of two characters: carriage return `\r` and new line `\n`. So you must include *\n* in your replace command as well:

`%s/\r\n//g`

If you want to stick with you original replace command, then you must first convert EOL-format of your file from Windows one to Unix one. You can use *dos2unix* tool to do that:

`$ dos2unix fileToConvert`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/\r$/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); printf "%s", $0; next} {print}' file
```

Comment: Is that a Vim command? The question was about Vim.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki, but the OP has tagged the question with `sed` too, so i don't see why an `awk` answer would not serve

Comment: I did tag it with sed, and I always like to see alternative solutions when in vim and on the command line. Thank you